# Custom Hotkeys in gvim

Tags: linux, vim

I am using gvim under linux and I really love it, the problem I have with it is that Shorcuts like Crlt+C doesn't work...
I added the following code to my gvimrc but it doesn't have any effect :/

```
nmap <C-V> "+gP
nmap <C-V> "+y
nmap <C-A> ggVG
nmap <C-Z> u
nmap <C-Y> ^R
```

Comment: Is it a typo in line `nmap <C-V> "+y`?

Comment: The commands work for me. But remind: `nmap` maps commands in command mode, not in insert mode. Use `imap` if you want them to work in insert mode (don't forget to add `<Esc>` to your mappings then).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not that the shortcuts don't work, rather than that you don't know what the shortcuts are supposed to do.

It might help for you if you add `behave mswin` to your `.vimrc`. It remaps many key bindings to behave more like other programs.